# How to enter server name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two clients.

I want connect another system, that system has the IP `192.168.0.222` and an instance name of `proc-job\MSSQLSERVER1` .

I server name I entered is `192.168.0.222\proc-job\MSSQLSERVER1` .

But I can't connect to that.

What's the problem?

When I entered `192.168.0.222` it connects to the default instance .

Comment: What error do you see when you try to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Take out the server name.  You don't need both the IP and server name when connecting to a SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you enter `192.168.0.222` in server name you created a  connection to a default instance listening on TCP address 192.168.0.222 using an IP address.
And when you tried to connect via `192.168.0.222\proc-job\MSSQLSERVER1` then `proc-job\MSSQLSERVER1` should be a `named instance`.

> An instance is either the default instance or a named instance. The
>   default instance name is MSSQLSERVER; SQLExpress for SQL Server
>   Express. It does not require a client to specify the name of the
>   instance to make a connection.  A named instance is determined by the
>   user during Setup. You can install SQL Server as a named instance
>   without installing the default instance first. The default instance
>   could be an installation of SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005, or SQL
>   Server 2008. Only one installation of SQL Server, regardless of
>   version, can be the default instance at one time.
>   You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531(v=sql.100).aspx

So for the default instance, it does not require a client to specify the name of the instance to make a connection. The client only has to know the server name. Ex: When you connected via `192.168.0.222` you actually connected to a default instance.

A named instance is identified by the network name of the computer plus the instance name that you specify during installation. The client must specify both the server name and the instance name when connecting. Ex: When you are trying to connect via 
server name `192.168.0.222` + an instance `\proc-job\MSSQLSERVER1` then it has to be a named instance.

By default, SQL Server installs in the default instance unless you specify an instance name. SQL Server Express, however, always installs in a named instance unless you force a default installation during setup.